# How to get the my table size after applying css styles

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am having one div, which contains one table. i want to apply the table-width to div element.
My table cells having padding 5, so table width is not correct in IE browser, while the mozila the sample code works.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting table's width to 100% using CSS? This will automatically resize it to fit the parent div's width.